# Java Eclipse (2020-09) Import launch configuration: Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: eclipse, crash

I'm trying to import a Launch configuration that I created before.

File->Import...->Run/Debug->Launch Configuration.

When I click on browse to locate the file I get a window with a message:
*Unhandled event loop exception. No more handles*

I have Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04

Log:

```
!SESSION 2020-11-03 07:13:14.813 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.17.0.I20200902-1800
java.version=11.0.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-11-03 07:10:50.509
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4895)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4784)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4755)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog.error(Dialog.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog.openNativeChooserDialog(DirectoryDialog.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog.open(DirectoryDialog.java:123)
        at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.importexport.launchconfigurations.ImportLaunchConfigurationsWizardPage$2.widgetSelected(ImportLaunchConfigurationsWizardPage.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5745)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1427)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5013)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4507)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5745)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1427)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5013)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4507)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

My gtk versions:

```
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64             3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3         amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-bin                 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3         amd64        programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-common              3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3         all          common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-dev:amd64           3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3         amd64        development files for the GTK+ library
ii  libgtk2-perl                 2:1.2498-1                amd64        Perl interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64            2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2  amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-bin                2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2  amd64        programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-cil                2.12.10-6                 amd64        CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 2.12
ii  libgtk2.0-common             2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2  all          common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-dev                2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2  amd64        development files for the GTK+ library
```

Comment: what Java version Eclipse runs on?

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, the issues might caused by a too old GTK version.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: I have now updated with log

Comment: Please show the log starting with `!SESSION` and tell which GTK version do you have. Since Ubuntu 16.04 is pretty old, it's very likely that a too old GTK version causing this issue.

Comment: I have updated with !SESSION log

Comment: Thanks, and what's the GTK version I asked for?

Comment: Sorry, though it was shown in the Session log. Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, [in Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) the **required minimum GTK** version has been increased from 3.14 to **3.20**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version), but you have 3.18.9 which probably causes this issue.

Comment: This looks like it will solve my problem.
Since I don't have time to upgrade my work computer right now I can't try it but I will still mark this as a solution